# MariaDB keeps throwing me error 1054, how can I fix it?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

So I been working with a system for years with several clients, and installed it on a server with MariaDB 10.3.22. It keeps throwing me errors with queries like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM ( (SELECT facturaaid 
         FROM vtiger_facturaa 
         INNER JOIN vtiger_crmentity ON crmid = facturaaid 
         WHERE facturaaid=46747) 
       UNION ALL 
       (SELECT IFNULL(idfactura,0)
        FROM vtiger_cobranza 
        WHERE idfactura=46747 
  GROUP BY idfactura) ) AS tabla      
WHERE facturaaid > 0;
```

This is the error

[image: Error]

Note that in the 2nd subquery it doesn't have any alias on the selected column. I saying this because when i write it down, it works perfectly. But if i write the second select like "SELECT idfactura" works just fine, so the problem (i guess) is operating over the column and not giving it an alias. I mean, the next query works well.

```
SELECT *
  FROM ( (SELECT facturaaid 
         FROM vtiger_facturaa 
         INNER JOIN vtiger_crmentity ON crmid = facturaaid 
         WHERE facturaaid=46747) 
       UNION ALL 
       (SELECT IFNULL(idfactura,0) as facturaaid
        FROM vtiger_cobranza 
        WHERE idfactura=46747 
  GROUP BY idfactura) ) AS tabla      
WHERE facturaaid > 0;
```

Or this one:

```
SELECT *
  FROM ( (SELECT facturaaid 
         FROM vtiger_facturaa 
         INNER JOIN vtiger_crmentity ON crmid = facturaaid 
         WHERE facturaaid=46747) 
       UNION ALL 
       (SELECT facturaaid 
        FROM vtiger_cobranza 
        WHERE idfactura=46747 
  GROUP BY idfactura) ) AS tabla      
WHERE facturaaid > 0;
```

Besides that I'm no writing any ORDER clause, I dont get why do I have to write the alias to get it working. The problem is that this is not the only query on the whole system that is this way, so I cant get all of them fixed, it will be a gigantic waste of time.

So my question is, do I need to downgrade the mariadb server edition (in older versions of mysql servers works perfectly, like Mysql 5)? or there's some configuration fix that I don't know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second UNION has form:

```
SELECT IFNULL(idfactura,0)
FROM vtiger_cobranza 
WHERE idfactura=46747 
GROUP BY idfactura
```

The error message refers to the `GROUP BY`. You probably want to write that as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT idfactura
FROM vtiger_cobranza 
WHERE idfactura=46747
```

The `IFNULL`-does not really make sense as `idfactura` cannot be `NULL` due to the condition. If you really want to use `GROUP BY` and `IFNULL` (which you should not as you do not have any aggregate functions in the query), you should use the full column definition as in `SELECT`:

```
SELECT IFNULL(idfactura,0)
FROM vtiger_cobranza 
WHERE idfactura=46747 
GROUP BY IFNULL(idfactura,0)
```

Comment: The IFNULL is just an example of operation over a column, the problem is that no matter which is it (ie. idfactura+1), I get that error. I want to avoid the need of giving an alias to it so I dont have to do it to the all others queries.. I mean it works fine with older versions of the database engine..

Comment: @DiegoB - The test and the `IFNULL` are not needed.  Remove them; you will still get the right answer.